# How to populate list data with dynamic array in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I have dynamic array which is formed after querying the database so how can i design my model and store  to set dynamic array and how can i populate the dynamic list data from dynamic array

Comment: In Ext JS, that is the default. When the user interacts with the dropdown (assumed that is what you meant by list), the store sends off its AJAX request to the backend and then uses the returned data.

Comment: No in my case list view it is i will be getting array of elements data  so how to map this array to model and store to populate in listview

Comment: The model needs to be the set up for each array element. Each array element should have the same properties. So set up the model just like one of the array elements and then pass in the whole array

Comment: I will be having different types of properties for each element in array

Comment: That's not really how drop downs work. I mean, typically, for dropdowns you have two things, the value that needs to be submitted and the value you want to display. These are configured in the comboxboxes `valueField` and `displayField` properties. But it kind of doesn't make sense to put things that aren't similar in nature in a dropdown box.